# Test Docker cluster in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration

I have some difficulties to configure Jenkins to run test on a dockerized application.

First here is my set up: the project is on bitbucket and I have a docker-compose that run my application which is composed of 3 three conmtainers for now (one for mongo, one for redis, one for my node app).

The webhook of bitbucket works well and Jenkins is triggered when I push.

However what i would like to do for a build is:
get a repo where my docker-compose is, run the docker-compose in order to have my cluster running, and then run a "npm test" inside the repo (my test use mocha), and finally having Jenkins notified if the test have passed or not.

If someone could help me to get this chain of operation applied by Jenkins, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is use jenkins pipeline plugin or shell script.

To build docker image and run compose you could use `docker-compose` command. Important thing is that you need rebuild docker image from compose level (because if you run `docker-compose run` only jenkins can use previous bilded image). So you need run `docker-compose build` before.

Your dockerfile should copy all files of your application.

Next when your service is ready you could run command in docker image using: `docker exec {CONTAINER_ID} {COMMAND_TO_RUN_TESTS}`.

Comment: I have a better idea now. But just is there a way to get the branch of the pull request.
I mean, i want to build all my container on the branch dev, but build the container that received a pull request on that pull request to run test before merging.
Example: if pull request on container 0 from a branch feature1:
build container 0 on feature1
Build other containers on branch dev
run tests.
So i would need to know that the pull request is from the  branch feature 1